# Terraria: Crystal ball buff/debuff

Tags: terraria-mobile

I bought this crystal ball from my cousin and placed it. When I click it I get some kind of buff/debuff. Everything seems normal. What is the buff/debuff and what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

The [Crystal Ball](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crystal_Ball) is a unique placed Hardmode furniture item that enables the Clairvoyance buff when placed and right-clicked. It also functions as a crafting station for some block types.

The Clairvoyance buff lasts for 10 minutes, and can be activated limitlessly, with no cooldown period. It can even be activated again while already active, to reset the 10-minute buff timer. The Crystal Ball is never consumed, and all players may use it to give themselves the buff. It is purchased from the Wizard for 10 Gold Coin.

Comment: If you're going to copy paste directly from the wiki it's worth linking it :P

Comment: Yeah thanks, somehow it just dident link it to the website. It was just blank so I left it :P